# Visual Studio Code - Ignore formatting of comments in JSX

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

How to disable formatting on comments in Visual Code? I use JSX/React. When the code is formatted the comments get realigned as well. How to avoid this?

Before formatting: 
[image: Before]

After formatting:
[image: After]

The comment should stay exactly as it was (it should be ignored). Which setting should be adjusted?

Comment: This is not standard VS Code behavior. It is coming from one of your extensions

Answer (score 0):

If you are using this plugin/extension.
https://github.com/kokororin/vscode-phpfmt

There is an option "RestoreComments" to not modify/touch the comment blocks.

File | Preferences | Settings

```
{
    "phpfmt.psr2": true,
    "phpfmt.visibility_order": true,
    "phpfmt.passes": [
        "PSR2KeywordsLowerCase",
        "PSR2LnAfterNamespace",
        "PSR2CurlyOpenNextLine",
        "PSR2ModifierVisibilityStaticOrder",
        "PSR2SingleEmptyLineAndStripClosingTag",
        "ReindentSwitchBlocks",
        "SpaceAfterExclamationMark",
        "ReplaceBooleanAndOr",
        "RestoreComments",
        "GeneratePHPDoc"
    ],
    "phpfmt.exclude": [
        "ReindentComments",
        "StripNewlineWithinClassBody"
    ],
    "[php]": {
        "editor.insertSpaces": true,
        "editor.tabSize": 4,
        "editor.autoIndent": true,
        "editor.formatOnSave": true
    }
}
```